# Is it okay to put error-prone code in an OR statement?

Tags: python

This is in Python, but can be applied to any language.

```
a = None
if (not a) or (a+3==5):
    print("Is this okay?")
```

Is it good programming practice to have `a+3` in the if statement, even though it would cause an error if `a` is `None`?

I'm relying on the `or` to stop before the error, which seems like a bad idea to me in case `a` is actually something else that doesn't support addition, or the `or` statement (in some other language) looks at both values.

What would be the best way to program this?

Comment: I'd like to note that `if key in dictionary and dictionary[key]` is a pretty common pattern.

Comment: In your example there would be no error thrown since not None is True, so the if condition immediately continued as soon as it found 1 true condition since this is an or statement.

Comment: I dunno what you're using it for, but `if hasattr(a,'__add__')....` might be what you want?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen That would still allow `'hello' + 3` for example

Comment: Here is the reference for python https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not and it is pretty common order of operation among languages. If the first statement is true the second will not be tested. If a might not be an int you might want to test for that also before doing `a+3==5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can depend on short-circuiting to perform error handling and validation.

However in your case, your logic is wrong, you would need `and` to perform this error handling

```
if a and (a+3==5):
```

Alternatively you could even do type checking

```
if isinstance(a, int) and (a+3==5):
```

Again this will short-circuit before reading the `+` operation

Comment: This would give incorrect results if `a` was `0`. I think you might need an explicit `if a!=None`.

Comment: My logic works fine (`not a` returns `True` so the `or` "short-circuits"), but yours is quicker and easier to read.